# can I use chrome://inspect to inspect android studio emulator

Tags: android-studio, webview, android-emulator, google-chrome-devtools

I have a mobile app apk file and want to run it through the android studio emulator and inspect network requests with chrome//inspect. To debug webview in the app.

But when I go to chrome//inspect. I can see the emulator but not inspect link.
[image]

I am not sure why the inspect link doesn't appear and whether I could inspect the emulator in the first place.
Suggesting me alternative ways to debug webview on Macbook will also be appreciated.

PC: Macbook 16 pro / MacOS Ventura 13.0.1

I don't have the source code of the app, Only apk file.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You also need to enable USB debugging inside the emulator in Android settings and in the browser.

Comment: @wOxxOm Hi, I enabled those but still didn't work

Comment: Hi @Shawn have you found a solution? even I have the same issue.
Thanks!

Comment: @Mudra Hi. I am sorry but I can't really recall how it ended up. But I think I went with some alternative.

Comment: @Shawn OK no worries, Thanks